# How to acces nested model's attributes in Play 2 templates

Tags: scala, attributes, playframework, nested, playframework-2.0

I've got those two models in a Play 2 project :

```
@Entity
public class Site extends Model{

    @Id
    public String adId;

    @Required
    public String name;

    @Required
    @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Room> rooms;
...
}//end of class
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Room extends Model {

    @Id
    @Required
    public String adId;

    @Required 
    public String name;

    public List<Reservation> reservations = new ArrayList<Reservation>();

...
}
```

When I use this code in my view.scala.html

```
            var treeData = [                            
                    @for(site <- sites) {
                        {title: "@site.name", tooltip: "@site.adId",
                            children: [
                                @for(room <- site.rooms) {
                                    {title: "@room.name", tooltip: "@room.adId"},
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                    }
                ];
```

I can't acces `site.rooms`
If I test it on the server side, the data exist.

Another strange thing is that I do get `site.adId`, but `site.name` stays empty...

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong...

(Sorry for the poor English, it's not my mother language).

Comment: Strange, looks normal. I assume you didn't override any getter in your model if so try to `@site.getName()` instead. On the other hand you don't need format your array in the template I think it would be better to use Json serializer in the controller and pass it to template as single variable of JsonNode type. Yo tagged question with scala and showed Ebean model, so are you using Scala or Java controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need getters for the data to be accessible in the templates / by scala. At least that what fixed it for me. I think I found that information on the [mailinglist](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/sMBvXTYhluU/nyXoOM0-vxYJ):

> This issue has been discussed before. You must use private field and
>   public accessor methods if you want to use Ebean lazy loading (or any
>   other Java magic) from Scala code.

Comment: It's not mandatory to set the fields private, but the use of getters/setters solves the problem. Thanks !

Comment: good to know, thanks. yet i think its good practice so either declare the fields private and use getters/setters or make them public. less confusion this way.

Answer (score 0):

Or fetch the data during the query: `finder.fetch("rooms")query().findList()`

Comment: While this would be fixing the issue, I think this is not the best way to go. If I understand this correctly, you'd have to think about every field you might want to output in the view (which is tedious and error prone, since you won't catch these errors at compile time) or simply fetch every column (which could get quite slow and works against one of Ebeans main goals, not having to fetch too much data via lazy loading/partial objects).